# How to flip UIImage horizontally?

Tags: ios, uiimage, uiimageorientation

How to flip the `UIImage` horizontally, I found `UIImageOrientationUpMirrored` enumeration value in the `UIImage` class reference, how to make use of this property to flip `UIImage`.

Comment: To add to aroth's fine answer, Apple explains the other types of image orientations very well at [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2)

Comment: As the accepted wasn't working for me, I found [this category](http://www.platinumball.net/blog/2010/01/31/iphone-uiimage-rotation-and-scaling/). Works like a charm.

Comment: If your app needs to support LTR and RTL, check out this question and its answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354498/flip-uiimageviews-for-right-to-left-languages

Answer (score 255, accepted):

Objective-C

```
UIImage* sourceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever.png"];

UIImage* flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:sourceImage.CGImage 
                                            scale:sourceImage.scale
                                      orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
```

Swift

```
let flippedImage = myImage.withHorizontallyFlippedOrientation()
```

Comment: There are two problems with this answer - scale isn't 1.0 at retina competible images and for some reason `UIImageOrientationUp` worked while `UIImageOrientationUpMirrored` didn't flip it. This worked - `image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:image.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp]`

Comment: @Kof as I noticed, the orientation parameter that you pass in is used to determine 'what the sourceImage's orientation is already' as opposed to 'give me this image with this specific orientation'. Hence, you can inspect sourceImage.imageOrientation parameter and pass in a different orientation to trick the method to give you what you want

Comment: It would be better to use `sourceImage.scale` for the scale.

Comment: How to do this in Swift?  [UIImage imageWithCGImage...] is not available there.

Comment: @LimThyeChean `UIImage(CGImage: CGImage!, scale: CGFloat, orientation: UIImageOrientation)`

Comment: This seems to completely break when I try to do `[flippedImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate]`. Any idea why?

Comment: @EgeAkpinar, That is incorrect. Using `UIImageOrientationDownMirrored`, flips the passed image over the horizontal axis.

Comment: This doesn't work for landscape and looks more like a hack

Comment: image disappears after `withHorizontallyFlippedOrientation`

Answer (score 78):

A very simple way you can achieve this is by creating a UIImageView instead of a UIImage and do the transform on UIImageView.

```
yourImageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever.png"];
yourImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1); //Flipped
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This ended up working much better for me than the `UIImage` manipulation, which I found had side effects when combined with `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate` rendering mode.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I had no luck with the "answer" to this puzzle associated with this post, but your answer worked phenomenally well and was only 1 line of code.

Comment: Works great! iOS 9+ now also includes flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection, but it won't work for iOS 8+ apps yet.

Comment: If you want to reset flipping, then use `yourImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity`

Comment: Note this method 'transforms' on UIImageView. It doesn't flip the actual UIImage.

Comment: If you need to transform the content, transform the container is not a reliable solution. If I need to save or send the image I couldn't just flip all UIImageViews, I need to flip the UImage...

Comment: Xcode doesn't even recognize this: `CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)`

Answer (score 36):

Vertical flip is often required to initialise OpenGL texture using `glTexImage2d(...)`. The above proposed tricks do not actually modify image data and will not work in this case. Here is a code to do the actual data flip inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/17909372

```
- (UIImage *)flipImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),CGRectMake(0.,0., image.size.width, image.size.height),image.CGImage);
    UIImage *i = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return i;
}
```

Comment: How does this flip image? It just looks like it draws the image again.

Comment: @Jonathan. I think it flips due to different coordinate systems (i.e. Y axis direction) while drawing.

Comment: Is there a way to use this to flip the image vertically?

Comment: this method nicely supports also image rendering - always template

Comment: To fix the quality issue, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, image.scale); instead.

Answer (score 16):

I have tried with imageFlippedForRightToLeftLayoutDirection, and creating a new UIImage with diferent orientations but at least this is the only solution I found for flipping my image

```
let ciimage: CIImage = CIImage(CGImage: imagenInicial.CGImage!)
let rotada3 = ciimage.imageByApplyingTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1))
```

As you can see in my playground it worked!! :)
[image]

And the, of course, let finalImage = UIImage(CIImage: rotada3)

Comment: Sorry but this looks like not working anymore, at least with camera taken pictures...

Answer (score 12):

As it Image Orientation Defines:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIImageOrientation) {
UIImageOrientationUp,            // default orientation
UIImageOrientationDown,          // 180 deg rotation
UIImageOrientationLeft,          // 90 deg CCW
UIImageOrientationRight,         // 90 deg CW
UIImageOrientationUpMirrored,    // as above but image mirrored along other axis. horizontal flip
UIImageOrientationDownMirrored,  // horizontal flip
UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored,  // vertical flip
UIImageOrientationRightMirrored, // vertical flip
};
```

I made some improvements for more circumstances like handling UIImage from AVCaptureSession.

```
UIImage* sourceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever.png"];
UIImageOrientation flipingOrientation;
if(sourceImage.imageOrientation>=4){
    flippedOrientation = sourceImage.imageOrientation - 4;
}else{
    flippedOrientation = sourceImage.imageOrientation + 4;
}
UIImage* flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:sourceImage.CGImage 
                     scale: sourceImage.scale orientation: flipingOrientation];
```

Answer (score 11):

This is a solid implementation to mirror/flip an UIImage horizontally, and can apply to the image back and forth. Since it changes the underlying image data, the drawing(like, screenshot) will also change. Tested to work, no quality loss.

```
func flipImage() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)
        let bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        bitmap.translateBy(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
        bitmap.scaleBy(x: -1.0, y: -1.0)

        bitmap.translateBy(x: -size.width / 2, y: -size.height / 2)
        bitmap.draw(self.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image?
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! but just wondering, how expensive is this one in terms of memory? Let's say doing this for 5 images a the same time. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

**iOS 10+**

```
[myImage imageWithHorizontallyFlippedOrientation];
```

Swift 4:

```
let flippedImage = myImage.withHorizontallyFlippedOrientation()
```

Comment: Banging my head against the wall that `imageWithHorizontallyFlippedOrientation` is supported but not `imageWithVerticallyFlippedOrientation`

Answer (score 9):

here's swift version: (I saw this question in comments)

```
let srcImage = UIImage(named: "imageName")
let flippedImage = UIImage(CGImage: srcImage.CGImage, scale: srcImage.scale, orientation: UIImageOrientation.UpMirrored)
```

Answer (score 6):

**For Swift 3/4:**

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
```

Comment: This is for a UIImageView, the OP is looking for a UIImage

Answer (score 5):

May be this will be of use for some:

```
    UIImageOrientation imageOrientation;

    switch (sourceImage.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
            imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationDownMirrored;
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationDown;
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
            imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored;
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationLeft;

            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationRightMirrored;

            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationRight;

            break;

        case UIImageOrientationUp:
            imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationUpMirrored;
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
            imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationUp;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    resultImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:sourceImage.CGImage scale:sourceImage.scale orientation:imageOrientation];
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple extension.

```
extension UIImage {

    var flipped: UIImage {
        guard let cgImage = cgImage else {
            return self
        }

        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: .upMirrored)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "imageName")
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image.flipped)
```

Comment: Extensions are one of the best features of Swift. I"m surprised that the original answers above failed to recommend that. I like this version a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working iOS8/9 compatible version:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] userInterfaceLayoutDirection] == UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionRightToLeft) {

    if ([image respondsToSelector:@selector(imageFlippedForRightToLeftLayoutDirection)]) {
        //iOS9
        image = image.imageFlippedForRightToLeftLayoutDirection;
    }
    else {
        //iOS8
        CIImage *coreImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage];
        coreImage = [coreImage imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];
        image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:coreImage scale:image.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    }
}

return image;
```

Comment: I dont think this is the best idea. This `imageFlippedForRightToLeftLayoutDirection ` is meant to be used with flipped layout directions - for example for arabic countries. So using this might not always work as desired.

Comment: Yes, you're correct - in my case it was exactly for RTL support. We all know code on SO is for reference and people don't really just copy/paste without understanding it first, right?

Answer (score 1):

**Tested in Swift 3 and above**

Here is the simple solution to achieve this problem with extensions.
I test it and it worked. You can mirror in any direction.

```
extension UIImage {

    func imageUpMirror() -> UIImage {
        guard let cgImage = cgImage else { return self }
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: .upMirrored)
    }

    func imageDownMirror() -> UIImage {
        guard let cgImage = cgImage else { return self }
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: .downMirrored)
    }

    func imageLeftMirror() -> UIImage {
        guard let cgImage = cgImage else { return self }
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: .leftMirrored)
    }

    func imageRightMirror() -> UIImage {
        guard let cgImage = cgImage else { return self }
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: .rightMirrored)
    }
}
```

Usage for this code

```
let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "imageName")
flipHorizontally = image.imageUpMirror()
```

So on, You can use other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of the answers above modified and in **Swift 3** that i found particularly useful when you have a button that needs to keep flipping the image back and forth.

```
func flipImage(sourceImage: UIImage,orientation: UIImageOrientation) -> UIImage {


        var imageOrientation = orientation

        switch sourceImage.imageOrientation {

        case UIImageOrientation.down:
            imageOrientation = UIImageOrientation.downMirrored;
            break;

        case UIImageOrientation.downMirrored:
            imageOrientation = UIImageOrientation.down;
            break;

        case UIImageOrientation.left:
            imageOrientation = UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored;
            break;

        case UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored:
            imageOrientation = UIImageOrientation.left;

            break;

        case UIImageOrientation.right:
            imageOrientation = UIImageOrientation.rightMirrored;

            break;

        case UIImageOrientation.rightMirrored:
            imageOrientation = UIImageOrientation.right;

            break;

        case UIImageOrientation.up:
            imageOrientation = UIImageOrientation.upMirrored;
            break;

        case UIImageOrientation.upMirrored:
            imageOrientation = UIImageOrientation.up;
            break;


        }


        return UIImage(cgImage: sourceImage.cgImage!, scale: sourceImage.scale, orientation: imageOrientation)

    }
```

Use:

```
imageToFlip: UIImage = flipImage(sourceImage: imageToFlip, orientation: imageToFlip.imageOrientation)
```

Answer (score 0):

aroth's answer in **SWIFT 3:**

```
let sourceImage = UIImage(named: "whatever.png")!
let flippedImage = UIImage(cgImage: sourceImage.cgImage!, scale: sourceImage.scale, orientation: .upMirrored)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

```
yourImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally considered low-quality. In addition to your code, explain how/why it works, fixes the problem, or answers the question.

Comment: Also, this doesn't work for the OPs question, as he is asking to flip the image. The code here flips the image view. Both are very different in terms of where they can be used. e.g. a button takes an image not an image view.

Comment: Also, you just copied my answer and wrote swift 4

Answer (score 0):

Due to unwrapping do the following:

```
let srcImage = UIImage(named: "myimage")!
let flippedImage = UIImage(cgImage: srcImage.cgImage!, 
                   scale: srcImage.scale, orientation: UIImage.Orientation.upMirrored)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can rotate the image as you want using this

**SWIFT 4**

```
extension UIImage {
public func imageRotatedByDegrees(degrees: CGFloat, flip: Bool) -> UIImage {
    let radiansToDegrees: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = {
        return $0 * (180.0 / CGFloat(M_PI))
    }
    let degreesToRadians: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = {
        return $0 / 180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)
    }

    // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
    let rotatedViewBox = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))
    let t = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: degreesToRadians(degrees));
    rotatedViewBox.transform = t
    let rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size

    // Create the bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
    let bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    bitmap.translateBy(x: rotatedSize.width / 2.0, y: rotatedSize.height / 2.0)
    // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    //CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width / 2.0, rotatedSize.height / 2.0);

    //   // Rotate the image context
    bitmap.rotate(by: degreesToRadians(degrees))
   // CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, degreesToRadians(degrees));

    // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    var yFlip: CGFloat

    if(flip){
        yFlip = CGFloat(-1.0)
    } else {
        yFlip = CGFloat(1.0)
    }
    bitmap.scaleBy(x: yFlip, y: -1.0)
    //CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, yFlip, -1.0)
    bitmap.draw(self.cgImage!, in: CGRect.init(x: -size.width / 2, y: -size.height / 2, width: size.width, height: size.height))
   // CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-size.width / 2, -size.height / 2, size.width, size.height), CGImage)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

Swift 5  -  Xcode 11.5

The best solution for rotates horizontally:
Watch this video:

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=4kSLbuB-MlU

Or use this code:

```
    
import UIKit
class FirstViewControl: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonAnim: UIButton!

    @IBAction func ClickOnButtonAnim(_ sender: UIButton) {    
        UIView.transition(with: buttonAnim, duration: 0.4, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animation: nil , completion: nil)
    }

}
```

You can use any ui(button or label or uiview or image) in this animation.

Comment: It is not recommended to post a link as an answer. The link could become invalid some day. If you believe the method is helpful, could you please post it here?