# CALayer - backgroundColor flipped?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, calayer

I'm creating a `CALayer` like this:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyPattern.png"]];
backgroundLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
[backgroundLayer setBackgroundColor:[color CGColor]];
[[self layer] addSublayer:backgroundLayer];
```

For some reason, the pattern is drawn upside down. I've already tried setting `geometryFlipped` and applying sublayer transforms, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `[backgroundLayer setTransform:CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, -1.0, 1.0)];` actually *does* work.

Comment: but it also flipped its sublayers, that i dont want

Answer (score 2):

I would rather use this method:

```
CALayer *backgroundLayer = [CALayer layer];

backgroundLayer.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200);

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyPattern.png"];

CGImageRef imgRef = CGImageRetain(img.CGImage);


backgroundLayer.contents = (id) imgRef;


[self.layer addSublayer:backgroundLayer];
```

This will provide image content inside the layer and it fits automatically, so it works great for backgrounds. Im not sure why your method isnt working, sorry about that, but I thought it would be nice to provide you with this method.

Comment: I'm using a background color because I want to tile the image, not stretch it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `CATransform3DMakeScale` you can flip image yourself:

```
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyPattern.png"];
img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img.CGImage
                          scale:img.scale 
                    orientation:UIImageOrientationDownMirrored];
UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img];
…
```

This works fine for me.

Or you can go further and actually redraw the image.

```
- (UIImage*)flipImage:(UIImage*)image {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),CGRectMake(0.,0., image.size.width, image.size.height),image.CGImage);
    UIImage* img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

Details why it can be useful are in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24799281/140592).

Comment: The first method did not work, but the second worked. Anyone knows why? 
The first worked when i used the image in a UIImageView but.