# AVCaptureStillImageOutput Image returning upside down

Tags: ios, avcapture

I am capturing images from the camera using `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection`

The images are being saved upside down. I tried saving the image using

```
UIImage *flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:image.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp]
```

but this orientation is only in the metadata and when I copy the data from the file to process it the processed images are upside down. (Quick look shows the originals upright, but the processed/filtered images are upside down).

What is the correct way to set the orientation for the video capturing?

I set the orientation on the video preview layer but that doesn't effect the captured data in the `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` object's buffer.

I read the `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` header but there doesn't seem to be an explanation of how to force the camera previews orientation to the image buffer.

e.g. `- (AVMetadataObject *)transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject:(AVMetadataObject *)metadataObject connection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "problem" is the image orientation, iOS camera returns images only in one orientation, except if you set the `-videoOrientation` property that transform already the image taken. So there can be different problems:

1. `videoOrientation` non set correctly
2. `videoOrientation` not set at ALL

The videoOrientation property works only for still images and video capturing, not for single buffers.
This snippet is tanken from Apple [AVCam](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code.

```
    [[[self stillImageOutput] connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] setVideoOrientation:[[(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[[self previewView] layer] connection] videoOrientation]];

    [AVCamViewController setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeAuto forDevice:[[self videoDeviceInput] device]];

    [[self stillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:[[self stillImageOutput] connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

        if (imageDataSampleBuffer)
        {
            NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
            [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[image imageOrientation] completionBlock:nil];
        }
    }]; <br>
```

First it sets the orientation according to the preview view, later it takes the shot, and later it saves it on the asset library with correct orientation

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, by doing that you are only changing the metadata.
You need to use this method to actually flip the image.

Try this:

```
- (UIImage *)flipImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height),image.CGImage);
    UIImage *i = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return i;
}
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24799281/1518538).