# how to get save horizontally mirror/flip image in an array or somewhere in objective c in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I try this -

```
    UIImage *flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:clickedImage.CGImage 
scale:clickedImage.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored]; //give the mirror uiimage object
```

This method give me mirror image but when i save these image in an array the original(not mirror) image is saved.

even when i debug it, it shows the original image. But shows mirror if displayed.

I don't know what is the reason but, i think this method actually does not convert image in mirror form.

How do i get horizontally flipped/mirror image?

Comment: How do you save it in the array? Let's see that code.

Comment: Do you update original `imageView` before saving like this: `clickedImage.image = flippedImage`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to flip UIImage horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404706/how-to-flip-uiimage-horizontally)

Comment: have you looked at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404706/how-to-flip-uiimage-horizontally

Comment: No, It is not duplicate, because question here is flipped image not saved in array, array contains original one. The flipping part was done by OP, all other people also misguide from question. Read again fella.

Comment: No, the question title clearly says ,how to get flipped image in iOS but not how to save the flipped image in array.

Comment: Maybe if OP change the title of his quesition , then it will not be a duplicate!!!

Comment: @Kampai i am saving the images in a array after get the flipped image using above code but when i use this array to print the images in GIF form it shows me the original images. that is my problem

Comment: @Mr.T i update the title as you said but i have also doubt in my code as i said when i debug it show original image on flippedImage. but in device it print mirrored if directly used.

Comment: please show us the code of how you are adding the image to array

Comment: UIImage *mFrameImg = [self getCurrentClickedImage];
    if (mFrameImg){
        [self.frameImgsArray addObject:mFrameImg];
    } and in getCurrentClickedImage i use above code to return flipped image

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get flipped image

```
   CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, image.CGImage);
        UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img.CGImage
                                   scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored];
```

Comment: i get blank white image using this code. i want mirror image like as when we click using front camera of phone and phone show the mirror or flipped image.