# How to flip a rotated UIView with any axis

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, transform

like this (note the yellow leaves and black corner):
[image]

and **without** flip container view. because I want to make a crop tool like iOS 9's Photos.app with flip feature. if flip container view, some user interaction will be different

[PhotoTweaks](https://github.com/itouch2/PhotoTweaks) is a good start, I just want flip content in the crop box

I think there is a way can implement this by just change the picture view's transform. but what I do just work on some angle，not all. my test code at [Github](https://github.com/qchenqizhi/PhotoTweaks/commits/master)

maybe I can make all angle works by try many times, like enum. but It not what I want. I want a math calculation method and theory.

forgive my poor English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to flip UIImage horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404706/how-to-flip-uiimage-horizontally)

Comment: no no no, it's very different. That question is easy to resolve.

Comment: In what way? Have you tried applying a transformation to the layer? like `imageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(v.layer.transform, CGFloat(M_PI), 0, 1, 0)`?

Comment: transform is not CALayer's propery. what's 'v' mean?

Comment: a damn, it is the same view, should be `imageView.layer.transform` as well.

Comment: transform is a layer property, yes.

Comment: sorry, my fault. I will put some code later

Comment: CATransform3DRotate(v.layer.transform, CGFloat(M_PI), 0, 1, 0) is not work.

Comment: I have pull the code to [Github](https://github.com/qchenqizhi/PhotoTweaks/commit/557845d0b5d9cecfa8a50a3c3e17d29795eb1bdd). you can have a look, It's really different question.

Comment: I have change the excample picture make question more clearly

Comment: @qlz, it's still just a horizontally-flipped image. Nothing a `transform` can't solve, or even `imageOrientation` on the image..

Comment: @jcaron Have you seen my [code](https://github.com/qchenqizhi/PhotoTweaks/commits/master) yet?  I have solved this by rotation and translation and mirror the source CGImage. but it still have some issue with some angle.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved the problem with simple solution.

Just make the angle between 0 - 360 degrees before rotation, and then the code work for all angle.

[This is the code at Github](https://github.com/qchenqizhi/PhotoTweaks/commits/master).

this question is **different** with [How to flip UIImage horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404706/how-to-flip-uiimage-horizontally), I think the duplicate tag need be removed.