# flip image in before send it to API as Base64 Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, image, xamarin.forms

I pick an image from the device and it's mirrored that's normal but I want to flip it horizontally before send it to API as to preview it after that normal not mirrored and do this on base64 string image.

Comment: Hi, have you solved this ?

Comment: Yes but managed to flip it when it bitmap not base64 on android and iOS the solution is in answers below

Comment: Great , saw it :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted all the information however. 
In Xamarin Forms Platform you can use FFImageLoading plugin which supports the transformation you are looking for. It support:

- FlipTransformation
- RotateTransformation

Follow the link to find their implementation here:
https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/blob/master/samples/ImageLoading.Forms.Sample/Shared/Pages/Transformations/FlipTransformationPage.xaml

Answer (score 0):

Your question did not explain clearly what you want to do.You can update it with more detail you want to conver what type to what type First.Whatever, I show a possible answer.

**image path to base64 string**：

```
// provide read access to the file
FileStream fs = new FileStream(media.Path, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
// Create a byte array of file stream length
byte[] ImageData = new byte[fs.Length];
//Read block of bytes from stream into the byte array
fs.Read(ImageData,0,System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
//Close the File Stream
fs.Close();
string _base64String = Convert.ToBase64String (ImageData);
```

**base64 string to byte[]**：

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String (FileRespone);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to flip the image as bitmap not Base64
in Android
https://acomputerengineer.wordpress.com/2016/06/07/flip-imagebitmap-horizontally-and-vertically-in-android/

in IOS:
[How to flip UIImage horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404706/how-to-flip-uiimage-horizontally)

```
UIImage sourceImage = uiImage;//[UIImage imageNamed: @"whatever.png"];

           UIImage flippedImage = sourceImage.GetImageFlippedForRightToLeftLayoutDirection();
               //[UIImage imageWithCGImage: sourceImage.CGImage    scale: sourceImage.scale  orientation: UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
```